# Is the mean CBM frequency more red-shifted since discovered in the 1960's?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, estimation, cosmic-microwave-background, redshift

If the universe is uniformly expanding at rate x, is possible to measure that the CBM has increased its red-shift value over time?  If the red-shift is a static value, is it possible that the approximately 13.5 billion light-year distance to CBM envelope simply indicates how long is takes for photons to be accelerated via expansion, away from us, at or beyond the speed light and disappear into the next De Sitter universe.

Answer (score 0):

The scale factor of the universe evolves according to the Hubble parameter.
$$\dot{a}= H_0 a_0$$

The temperature of the CMB is inversely related to the scale factor, so 
$$ T = T_0 (a_0/a)$$
$$\dot{T} \simeq -T_0 H_0$$

For $H_0 \sim 70$ km/s/Mpc and $T_0=2.7$ K, then the rate of change of temperature is $2\times 10^{-12}$ K/year. So yes, the CMB should be cooler by about $10^{-10}$K than it was in the 60s. The peak frequency will decrease (according to Wien's law) by a similar proportion.